# Sort of Arraylist

Tags: sorting, arraylist

I have code:

```
  List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("10.160.0.100;14/Nov/201107:22:38;/;-;");
    list.add("10.160.0.100;14/Nov/201108:54:31;/;-;");
    list.add("10.160.0.10;16/Nov/201112:56:38;/;-;");

    list.add("10.160.0.100");
    list.add("10.160.0.100");
    list.add("10.160.0.10");


    Collections.sort(list);
    for (String temp : list) {
        System.out.println(temp);
    }
```

Output is:

> 10.160.0.10
>
> 10.160.0.100
>
> 10.160.0.100
>
> 10.160.0.100;14/Nov/201107:22:38;/;-;
>
> 10.160.0.100;14/Nov/201108:54:31;/;-;
>
> 10.160.0.10;16/Nov/201112:56:38;/;-;

**Why ? I need this output:**

> 10.160.0.10
>
> 10.160.0.100
>
> 10.160.0.100
>
> 10.160.0.10;16/Nov/201112:56:38;/;-;
>
> 10.160.0.100;14/Nov/201107:22:38;/;-;
>
> 10.160.0.100;14/Nov/201108:54:31;/;-;

Comment: Your required output is not sorted in any way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because in ASCII, the `;` character has a higher number than the `0` character.

[image]